# Custom Tableview getting crash in iPhone5(iOS7)

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios7, iphone-5

In my app i am using two table one for filter the data and second for results data. I am using the following line to scroll the tableview at selected index position,

```
self.indexPaths = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:indexPath.row];

 [tableview scrollToRowAtIndexPath:self.indexPaths atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];

    [tableview reloadData];
```

but my app is getting crash in only in iPhone5(iOS7) and working fine in all devices even iPhone5(iOS6).

Why does this crash only on iPhone5(iOS7)?

Crashing log is: Terminating app due to uncaught exception `'NSInvalidArgumentException'`

Comment: It helps, when asking questions about crashes, to actually include the crash log in the question.

Comment: Usually that error tells you what illegal argument was passed to what object in which method, which would have pointed out the root of the problem as the current answers suggest.

Answer (score 4):

You pass integer (0) for index path. You should pass NSIndexPath instead, try:

```
    NSIndexPath *ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    [tableview scrollToRowAtIndexPath:ip atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 2):

`NSIndexPath` is an object so you can't pass **0**.

Try `[NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex:0]`

Answer (score 0):

```
self.indexPaths = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:indexPath.row];
```

the RHS returns the indexpath corresponding to a row and section.

in the above code,
you are passing `indexpath.row` to `inSection` parameter. This may be wrong.Assume, you have 1 section and 5 rows. when `indexpath.row = 4`(for eg), there wont be a section corresponding to 4 and hence `self.indexPaths` becomes `nil` since the system would try to look for row 4 in section 4, but section 4 doesnt exist!!
Consequently, when you pass nil to below line, it says `nsinvalidargument` exception.

```
 tableview scrollToRowAtIndexPath:self.indexPaths atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply,
but its working fine in all device except iPhone5

Comment: may be the particular row to which you're trying to scroll is out of view and hence it's non reachable!